# Question about "THE MORSE INEQUALITIES"in Milnor's book

Tags: algebraic-topology, morse-theory

in this paragraph what is $H_{*}$ ?
[image]

Please help me

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

$H_*$ is homology.  An equation $H_*(\text {this})=H_*(\text{that})$ means that $H_k(\text {this})=H_k(\text{that})$ for all $k$.

Comment: ok thank you, please what it means : coefficient group in dimension $\lambda_i$ ? please thak you

Answer (score 1):

Singular [homology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_%28mathematics%29).  There is a homology group $H_q$ in each dimension $q \ge 0$, and $H_*$ refers to all of them at once.

Comment: ok thank you, please what it means : coefficient group in dimension $\lambda_i$ ? please thak you

Comment: If the coefficient group is $G$, then $H_{\lambda_i}(e^{\lambda_i}, \overset{\circ}{e}^{\lambda_i}) \cong G$.  (The homology of a disk relative to its boundary is rank $1$ in the dimension of the disk.)